# Изменить цвет заливки chart openpyxl python

Tags: python, openpyxl

Не получается изменить цвет заливки графика с помощью метода:

```
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart
from openpyxl.chart.shapes import GraphicalProperties
props = GraphicalProperties(solidFill="999999") 
chart.graphicalProperties = props
```

Получается только для plot_area. А для общей области невозможно.

Comment: Советую задать этот вопрос на английской версии SO - там Charlie Clark (один из авторов OpenPyxl) отвечает на вопросы по `openpyxl` (если метка у вопроса соотвествующая)